# How can I loop through a vector of objects stored within a map? C++

Tags: c++, vector, iteration

I have a function class with a vector variable that stores other function objects. Each function is mapped in a network class.

```
std::map<std::string, Function> functions;
```

When I output a single object it shows the vector variable (`next_func`) of that object after mapping the function.

```
cout << network.functions.at("C");
```

*Output:*

```
(FUNCTION: id=C, next_func=[D])
```

However when I try to loop through the map to try and display the vector variable for each mapped function, it show an empty vector variable.

```
for (auto element : network.functions) {
    cout << element.second << "\n";
}
```

*Output:*

```
(FUNCTION: id=C, next_func=[])
(FUNCTION: id=D, next_func=[])
(FUNCTION: id=E, next_func=[])
```

I'm not sure if it's something to do with my class structures or if I'm not using an appropriate form of iteration for what I need done.

How can I loop through the mapped objects to display/manipulate the objects within the vector variable?

Working example:

Function.h

```
#ifndef Function_H
#define Function_H

#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Function {
public:
    string name;
    std::vector<Function*> func_pre;
    std::vector<Function*> func_next;
public:  
    Function();
    Function(const string& id, int duration);
    Function(const Function&);
    ~Function();
    Function& operator=(const Function& t);
    string name_() const;
    void addNext(Function& s);
    void addPre(Function& p);
    std::string toString() const;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Function&);
};
#endif
```

Function.cpp

```
#include <sstream>
#include "Function.h"

using namespace std;

Function::Function() {
    name = "";
}

Function::Function(const string& id, int duration) {
    this->name = id;
}

Function::Function(const Function& t) {
    this->name = t.name_();
}

Function::~Function() {}

Function& Function::operator=(const Function& t) {
    if (this != &t) {
        name = t.name;
    }
    return *this;
}

string Function::name_() const {
    return this->name;
}

void Function::addNext(Function& s) {
    Function* e = &s;
    func_next.push_back(e);
}

void Function::addPre(Function& p) {
    Function* e = &p;
    func_pre.push_back(e);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const Function& e) {
    s << e.toString();
    return s;
}

std::string Function::toString() const {
    std::string s = "(Function: id=" + name +" ,to=";
    s = s+"[";
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < func_next.size(); i++)
        s = s + func_next[i]->name_() + " ";
    s = s+"], from=[";
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < func_pre.size(); i++)
        s = s + func_pre[i]->name_() + " ";
    s = s + "])";
    return s;
}
```

Map.h

```
#ifndef Map_H
#define Map_H

#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Function.h"

class Map{

public:
    std::map<std::string, Function> fucntions;
public:
    explicit Map();
    Map(const Map& n);
    ~Map();
    Map& operator=(const Map& i);
    void addFunction(const string id, int x);
    void addDep(const string& from, const string& to);
    std::string toString()const;
};
#endif
```

Map.cpp

```
#include "Map.h"
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

Map::Map() {
    fucntions = {};
}

Map::Map(const Map& n) {
    this->fucntions = n.fucntions;
}

Map::~Map() {
}

Map& Map::operator=(const Map& i) {
    if (this != &i) {
        fucntions = i.fucntions;
    }
    return *this;
}

void Map::addFunction(const string id, int x) {
    Function t(id, x);
    fucntions[t.name_()] = t;
}

void Map::addDep(const string& from, const string& to) {
    fucntions.at(from).addNext(fucntions.at(to));
    fucntions.at(to).addPre(fucntions.at(from));
}

std::string Map::toString() const {
    std::string s = "(\n";
    std::map<std::string, Function>::const_iterator i = fucntions.begin();
    std::map<std::string, Function>::const_iterator end = fucntions.end();
    if (i == end)
        s += "<Empty>";
    else
        do{
            s += (*i).second.toString();
            if (++i != end) s+= ",\n";
        }while (!(i==end));
    s +="\n)";
    return s;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Map.h"
#include "Function.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Map m;
    m.addFunction("A", 10);
    m.addFunction("B", 30);
    m.addFunction("C", 20);
    m.addFunction("D", 40);
    m.addFunction("E", 20);
    m.addDep("A", "B");
    m.addDep("A", "C");
    m.addDep("B", "D");
    m.addDep("D", "E");
    m.addDep("C", "E");
    m.addDep("B", "C");

    cout << m.fucntions.at("C") << "\n\n";

    for (auto& element : m.fucntions) {
        cout << "Predecessor counts: " << element.first
                << " : "<< element.second << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `Function` have a working copy constructor?  Does anything change if you do `for (auto& element : network.functions)`?

Comment: And what is `Function`? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: @aschepler Yes it does have a working copy constructor, and it works after I add `&`. Is this because it is now returning a copy of the vector, whereas before it wasn't?

Comment: @rks No, `&` makes a variable to a reference. After using `&`, no copy is made. When you are not using `&`, a copy is made. Since it works while using `&`, your copy-constructor or assignment-operator seems to have a bug. Without an example as described by Joachim Pileborg, I can't say anything else.

Comment: I have added a working example, sorry it's so long I did my best to scale back.

Comment: It would be easier on the readers with `Function.h` first.

Comment: Fixed as per above ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This copy constructor

```
Function::Function(const Function& t) {
    this->name = t.name_();
}
```

… leaves the pointer members with indeterminate values.

With some compilers and options you may get nullpointer values but this is not guaranteed: formally accessing the values of those pointer members is Undefined Behavior.

---

Additionally, this copy assignment operator,

```
Function& Function::operator=(const Function& t) {
    if (this != &t) {
        name = t.name;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

… does not assign the pointer members. Whether that is technically an error or not depends on your logic. But it does look like a bug, because it's an assignment that doesn't preserve the full assigned value.

---

Tip: instead of initializing members via assignment, you can do that via a constructor's member initializer list, like this:

```
Function::Function( Function const& other )
    : name( other.name )
    , func_pre( other.func_pre )
    , func_next( other.func_next )
{}
```

This has the advantage of avoiding extra default-initializations, and it works for members that are non-assignable but copyable.

This particular implementation example is exactly what the compiler generates for you if you just don't define or declare a copy constructor.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look over my code. I've changed the Function copy constructor to `this->name = t.name;` instead. But I'm not sure how I can get the Function assignment operator to preserve the assigned value.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code in your main.cpp

```
for (map<string,Function>::iterator element=m.fucntions.begin();element!=m.fucntions.end();element++) {
    cout <<"Predecessor counts: " <<  element->first << " : "<< element->second << "\n";
}
```

Output I obtained is

```
Predecessor counts: A : (Function: id=A ,to=[B C ], from=[])
Predecessor counts: B : (Function: id=B ,to=[D C ], from=[A ])
Predecessor counts: C : (Function: id=C ,to=[E ], from=[A B ])
Predecessor counts: D : (Function: id=D ,to=[E ], from=[B ])
Predecessor counts: E : (Function: id=E ,to=[], from=[D C ])
```

I have implemented c++98 loop iterator, I am unable to figure out error in your for loop but I guess my solution helps you.